# Measures with common distribution function

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $\varphi: [0, \infty) → [0, \infty]$ be growing monotonously. $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are two (finite) measures on $([0, \infty), B([0, \infty)))$ and $\varphi$ is their distribution function. how can i show, that $\tau_1 = \tau_2$?

Comment: Standard text book material. See, for example, Rudins RCA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I'm sorry for asking such a basic question, but I'm stuck with the proof. I showed that $\varphi$ is measurable but don't know how to show the identity of the two measures. I have $\varphi(x) = \tau_1([0,x]) = \tau_2([0,x]) \forall x \in [0,\infty)$ but don't know how to continue from that point on.

Comment: The standard argument is to prove that the measures are equal on the class of all finite disjoint unions of intervals $(a,b]$ which form an algebra generating the Borel sigma algebra.